# How to prevent the azure cloud shell to show directories in solid green?

Tags: colors, directory, display, azure-cloud-shell

Please look at the following screenshot of my azure cloud shell:

[image]

I find the solid green coloring for directories very annoying and hard to read especially if you more directories other than the default "." and "..".  Is there any way to adjust the shell to NOT color the directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [`dircolors`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dircolors) command, it's used to set up the color for command `ls`. And there are also different colors for different types of directories. So you need to take care of which type of the directory you want to change the color.

For example, the origin situation:

[image]

Then I change the `OTHER_WRITABLE` from `34;42` into `01;32` and it looks like this:

[image]

Note: Change it carefully and remember what does the color mean.

Update:

output the current setting:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

Change the color as you need, here is an example:

[image]

Apply the new setting:

```
dircolors -b ~/.dircolors
```

Then open a new terminal, the new setting will be in use. Suggest you first backup before changing.

Comment: Hello Charles, Can you please give me the command that you typed in at the bash prompt to make '.azure' not be high lighted with a green background?  That would be a big help.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bharat See the updates. And the changes not only work on the '.azure', but it also works on all the things you have changed.

Comment: Thank you.  Excellent explanation.  Really appreciate it.  This has really improved my Cloud Shell experience tremendously!

Comment: @Bharat It's my pleasure. Cheers!